# Localization of polynomial ring as differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals, localization

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ be a point and $S=\mathbb{R}[x]_{(x-a)}$ the localization of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$ with maximal ideal $(x-a)$.

i) Describe the elements of $S$ as differentiable functions on $\mathbb{R}$, defined on a neighbourhood of $a$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

ii) Show that there is not one neighbourhood for all functions in $S$.

---

I'm really unsure how to tackle this one. 
For i) I'd take the function $f:[a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon] \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=\frac{p(x)}{(x-a)}$ where $p(x)$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x=a$. Does that make sense?

For ii) I don't know exactly how I might prove that. Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: $S=\{f(x)/g(x):f,g\in\mathbb R[x], g(a)\ne 0\}$.

Comment: @user26857 I see, so that would give me then the differentiable functions. How do I go there to part ii). I have to show, that the neighbourhoods in $S$ are disjoint? Maybe does that mean that $S$ would be hausdorff?